# how to add int number of array to variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$pagename = 'index.html';
$dbh = connectDb();
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $dbh->query("select 'tcount' from accessNum where pagename = '$pagename'");
$record = $stmt->fetchAll();

if (sizeof($stmt) != 0) {
    $counter = $record['tcount'];
    $counter++;
    $dbh->exec("update accessNum set tcount = '$counter' where pagename = '$pagename'");
}
```

```
mysql (table name is accessNum) is
pagename(varchar(255)) = index.html,
today(date) = 2015-08-31,
tcount(int(11)) = 1,
totalcount(int(11)) = 1,
```

the tcount keeps 1 every update.  why it occurs?

Comment: Wrap off quotes form `'tcount'` !! from your query

Comment: Doing `select 'tcount'` will *literally* select the string `'tcount'`.  It will not get the value of the column.  It's like doing `SELECT 1`.

Comment: sorry, i understand what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with int you don't need quotes on variable like this

```
if (sizeof($stmt) != 0) {
    $counter = $record['tcount'];
    $counter++;
    $dbh->exec("update accessNum set tcount = $counter where pagename = '$pagename'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need quotes around a column name in a `SELECT` query

```
$stmt = $dbh->query("select tcount from accessNum where pagename = '$pagename'");
```

Also, you do not need quotes around a number in an `UPDATE` query

```
$dbh->exec("update accessNum set tcount = $counter where pagename = '$pagename'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Always escape column and table names with backticks, and values with quotes. They're quite different in MySQL. This should work:

```
$pagename = 'index.html';
$dbh = connectDb();
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $dbh->query("select `tcount` from `accessNum` where `pagename` = '$pagename'");
$record = $stmt->fetchAll();

if (sizeof($stmt) != 0) {
    $counter = $record['tcount'];
    $counter++;
    $dbh->exec("update `accessNum` set `tcount` = '$counter' where `pagename` = '$pagename'");
}
```